# Does PHP have static or dynamic scoping?

Tags: php, function, scope

Static scoping : The function sees the variable from parent function first.
Dynamic scoping : The function sees the variable from the function that calls the current function first.

Is there these kind of concepts in PHP? Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Simple google seartch et voila: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These concepts do not exist in PHP. Every function has its own scope.

Therefore PHP has a **function scope**.
That means: functions do only have access to *their own variables* (the variables declared inside the function, or function params) and code outside of functions does only have access to variables that are declared outside functions.
(You can declare variables [global](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) to access them inside functions - but thats not recommended.)

If you want to know more about the PHP variable scope read this answer from deceze. He made a good job explaining this topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16959577